# Real part of a complex exponential with a complex amplitude

Tags: complex-numbers

I have $z=(x+yi)e^{it}$ and am stuck trying to find the real part.

I tried applying Euler's identity, but I'm pretty sure that's the wrong way to approach this problem. What am I missing?

$$z=(x+yi)\cos{t}+(x+yi)i\sin{t}$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Is $t$ real?  Distribute $\cos t$ and $i \sin t$ and then take the real part

Comment: t is real. This just seemed too obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $t$ is real, then you are on the right track
$$z=(x+yi)\cos{t}+(x+yi)i\sin{t}$$
Multiplying everything
$$z=x\cos t+iy\cos{t}+x\sin t-y\sin{t}$$
Then grouping the real term and the imaginary one
$$z=(x\cos t -y\sin t) +i(x\sin t +y\cos t)$$